# Query based on recorded criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables,

```
Categories(Id, Name)
Products(Id, Text, CategoryId)
```

There is another table for filtering products:

```
Filter(CategoryIds, ContainText)
```

CategoryIds in Filter table is a comma-separated: 100,101

We want to query products based on criteria extracted from Filters table.

Example:
Filters have only two records:

```
CategoryIds   |   ContainText
-----------------------------
100,101       |   A
200,201       |   B
```

Here are products we want to query:

```
containting text 'A' in categories 100 or 101
```

Or

```
containting text 'B' in categories 200 or 201
```

We would not like to use dynamic query.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Comment: Your `Filter` tables needs normalizing. Storing comma separated values like this is a very bad idea.

Comment: if you have any idea to normalizing Filter table please hint me.

Comment: I think it has clear data, there are some products by some categories.

Comment: You need to change it to 2 tables, one for the text and one for the categories linked to that text.

Comment: I will try add some data and expected results anyway.

Comment: You also need to [read this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea to change Filter table to 2 tables. thank you. but I think the query will be complicated anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As per Giorgos comment, you need to normalize your `Filter` table. If you're stuck with this design, here is a solution:

First, you need to have a string splitter. Here is one taken from Aaron Bertrand's [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

---

Then, you need to split your `Filter` table into separate rows. Then do `JOIN`s on the `Products`, `Categories` and the splitted `Filter` table:

```
WITH CteFilter(CategoryId, ContainText) AS(
    SELECT
        CAST(s.Item AS INT), f.ContainText
    FROM Filter f
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(f.CategoryIds, ',') s
)
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN Categories c
    ON c.Id = p.CategoryId
INNER JOIN CteFilter f
    ON f.CategoryId = c.Id
    AND p.Text LIKE '%' + f.ContainText + '%'
```

Comment: @JafarElahi No problem. If you could normalize your table, I suggest you do so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming normalization is possible, here is a simple query that will do the trick:

**Create sample tables:**

```
DECLARE @Categories as table 
(
    id int identity(1,1), 
    name char(1)
)

DECLARE @Products as table 
(
    id int identity(1,1), 
    name varchar(100),
    categoryId int
)

DECLARE @Filter as table 
(
    id int identity(1,1), 
    ContainText varchar(100)
)

DECLARE @FilterCategories as table 
(
    FilterId int, 
    CategoryId int,
    PRIMARY KEY(filterId, CategoryId)
)
```

**Populate sample tables:**

```
INSERT INTO @Categories 
VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E')

INSERT INTO @Products (name, categoryId) 
VALUES ('cat A', 1),('category A', 1), ('cat B', 2), ('category B', 2)

INSERT INTO @Filter 
VALUES ('gory'), ('cat')

INSERT INTO @FilterCategories 
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)
```

**The query:**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT p.id As ProductId, 
        p.name As ProductName,
        c.name As CategoryName
FROM @Filter f
INNER JOIN @FilterCategories fc ON(f.id = fc.FilterId)
INNER JOIN  @Products p ON(p.categoryId = fc.CategoryId)
INNER JOIN @Categories c ON(p.categoryId = c.id)
WHERE p.name LIKE '%'+ f.ContainText +'%'
```

**Results:**

```
ProductId   ProductName                    CategoryName
----------- ------------------------------ ------------
1           cat A                          A
2           category A                     A
4           category B                     B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the below query which does not require normalization. So in case you are unable to update your tables, try the below query which is simple `JOIN`

```
--create table categories(id int, name varchar(100));
--create table products(id int, text varchar(100), categoryid int);
--create table filters(categoryids varchar(100), containtext varchar(10));
--insert into filters values
--('100,101','A'),
--('200,201','B');
--insert into products values 
--(1,'Random',100),
--(2,'rps',101),
--(3,'rps',200),
--(4,'rpsb',201);
--insert into categories values 
--(100,'Cat100'),
--(101,'Cat101'),
--(200,'Cat200'),
--(201,'Cat201');

select 
  P.*,C.Name 
from Products P join Categories C 
      on C.Id=P.CategoryId 
join Filters F 
     on text like '%'+ContainText+'%' 
          and   ','+ CategoryIds +',' like '%,'+cast(C.ID as varchar(100)) +',%'
```

Comment: Good approach! but I think performance will not be efficient. because product table is a big table and string operation on it will be low actually.

Comment: @JafarElahi The performance will be below par when you compare against a normalized table where we store category id as int.  However if you are stuck with design, you may go this route. The query took 4 seconds on my machine for a million rows.

Answer (score 0):

To normalize `Filters` table you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

;WITH Filters AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('100,101', 'A'),
('200,201', 'B'),
('300,301,302', 'C')
) as t(CategoryIds, ContainText)
)

SELECT @xml =(
SELECT CAST ('<b>' + ContainText + '<a>'+REPLACE(CategoryIds,',','</a><a>') + '</a></b>' as xml)
FROM Filters
FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT  t.v.value('../.','nvarchar(1)') as ContainText,
        t.v.value('.','int') as CategoryId
FROM @xml.nodes('/b/a') as t(v)
```

Output:

```
ContainText CategoryId
----------- -----------
A           100
A           101
B           200
B           201
C           300
C           301
C           302

(7 row(s) affected)
```

Then you can join this table to `Products` and `Categories`:

```
SELECT *
FROM NormFilters nf
INNER JOIN Categories c  -- (Id, Name)
    ON nf.CategoryId = c.Id
INNER JOIN Products p  --(Id, Text, CategoryId)
    ON c.CategoryId = p.CategoryId AND p.[Text] LIKE '%' + nf.ContainText +'%'
```